# Exclude a file from SonarQube SCM blame?

Tags: svn, version-control, sonarqube, blame, sonarqube-5.0

Is it possible to exclude a file from Sonar's SCM blame data gathering?

I have a file at this path: `./projects/ichrg/ichrg.Web/bottombar.cs`

svn blame from a command line works fine on the file, but when I run it with sonar I get the following error:

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException**:
>
> The svn blame command:
>
> `svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w --username ********
>   --password ******** --trust-server-cert BottomBar.cs`
>
> failed:
>
> **svn: warning: W155010:** The node
>   `'D:\JenkinsBuilds\svntrunk\projects\ichrg\ichrg.Web\BottomBar.cs'` was
>   not found.
>
> **svn: E200009:** Could not perform blame on all targets because some
>   targets don't exist

Which sounds like it's probably an svn problem.

For now, I just want to exclude the file in question from SCM analysis, I added the following pattern to the "Source File Exclusions" property in the web portal, under "File Exclusions":

`**/bottombar*`

But it continues to try to get blame data for the file.

Is there someway else I can prevent sonar from trying to get blame data for my file?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28740785/59087

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File exclusions is case sensitive, so you should do the following to exclude your file:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/BottomBar.cs
```

Concerning your initial problem which is related to SCM information, SonarQube will be less strict about such failures in the upcoming 5.1 version. Please see "[SONAR-6172 - Do not fail when a file has no blame information](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6172)".